# Laravel 5 on Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-5

I follow this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel) and did all these steps

```
  composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist deployLaravel
  cd deployLaravel/
  git init
  git add .
  git commit -m "new laravel project"
  echo web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/ > Procfile
  git add .
  git commit -m "Procfile for Heroku"
  heroku login --> input my credential
  heroku create
  heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php
  heroku config:set
  git push heroku master
```

I kept getting

```
Counting objects: 195, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (173/173), done.
Writing objects: 100% (195/195), 230.37 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 195 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/php
remote: -----> PHP app detected
remote: -----> Bootstrapping...
remote: -----> Installing platform packages...
remote:        NOTICE: No runtime required in composer.json; requirements
remote:        from dependencies in composer.lock will be used for selection
remote:        - php (7.0.5)
remote:        - ext-mbstring (bundled with php)
remote:        - ext-mcrypt (bundled with php)
remote:        - apache (2.4.18)
remote:        - nginx (1.8.1)
remote: -----> Installing dependencies...
remote:        Composer version 1.0.0-beta2 2016-03-27 16:00:34
remote:        Loading composer repositories with package information
remote:        Installing dependencies from lock file
remote:          - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (0.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v1.1.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v2.6.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/translation (v2.6.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/security-core (v2.6.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/routing (v2.6.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/process (v2.6.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v2.6.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.6.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/debug (v2.6.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v2.6.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/finder (v2.6.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/console (v2.6.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.3.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing nikic/php-parser (v1.1.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.3.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (0.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing psy/psysh (v0.4.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.17.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing mtdowling/cron-expression (v1.0.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing monolog/monolog (1.13.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing jeremeamia/superclosure (2.1.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing ircmaxell/password-compat (v1.0.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.0.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing danielstjules/stringy (1.9.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/filesystem (v2.6.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing classpreloader/classpreloader (1.2.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing laravel/framework (v5.0.16)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:        Generating optimized autoload files
remote:        > php artisan clear-compiled
remote:        > php artisan optimize
remote:        Generating optimized class loader
remote:        Compiling common classes
remote:        PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use 'PhpParser\Node\Scalar\String' as class name as it is reserved in /tmp/build_de199b8f80b0042db01dc400effcc6bc/vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PhpParser/PrettyPrinter/Standard.php on line 86
remote:        
remote:        
remote:                                                                                     
remote:          [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                    
remote:          Cannot use 'PhpParser\Node\Scalar\String' as class name as it is reserved  
remote:                                                                                     
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
remote:        
remote:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
remote:          [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
remote:          Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use 'PhpParser\Node\Scalar\String' as class name as it is reserved in /tmp/build_de199b8f80b0042db01dc400effcc6bc/vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PhpParser/PrettyPrinter/Standard.php on line 86  
remote:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
remote:        
remote:        install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
remote:        
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to enigmatic-lake-32642.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/enigmatic-lake-32642.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/enigmatic-lake-32642.git'
```

---

I've tried this 3 times now. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Somehow your version of Laravel is set to 5.0.16, rather than the latest stable version which is 5.2.27. In fact, most of your dependencies are outdated. The reason you're getting the error is because PHP-Parser had used the word "String" as a class name in its source code, which is now a reserved keyword in PHP-7, which you're running in your Heroku environment. Try getting rid of `--prefer-dist` and see what happens. [This issue had been resolved a year ago](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/issues/192).

Comment: @maiorano84 : I tried it again, create another Laravel project, and take off `--prefer-dist`, still see the same problem. Should I adjust my `composer.json` ?